# How to run shell script in few jobs

Tags: shell, unix

I have a build script, which works very slowly, especially on Solaris. I want to improve its performance by running it in multiple jobs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Try [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), it is quite easy to use:

> GNU parallel is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one or more computers. A job can be a single command or a small script that has to be run for each of the lines in the input. The typical input is a list of files, a list of hosts, a list of users, a list of URLs, or a list of tables. A job can also be a command that reads from a pipe. GNU parallel can then split the input and pipe it into commands in parallel.
>
> If you use xargs and tee today you will find GNU parallel very easy to use as GNU parallel is written to have the same options as xargs. If you write loops in shell, you will find GNU parallel may be able to replace most of the loops and make them run faster by running several jobs in parallel.
>
> GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as you would get had you run the commands sequentially. This makes it possible to use output from GNU parallel as input for other programs.
>
> For each line of input GNU parallel will execute command with the line as arguments. If no command is given, the line of input is executed. Several lines will be run in parallel. GNU parallel can often be used as a substitute for xargs or cat | bash.

---

You mentioned that it is a build script. If you are using command line utility `make` you can parallelize builds using [make's `-j<N>` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel):

> GNU make knows how to execute several recipes at once. Normally, make will execute only one recipe at a time, waiting for it to finish before executing the next. However, the ‘-j’ or ‘--jobs’ option tells make to execute many recipes simultaneously.

Also, there is [`distcc`](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) which can be used with `make` to distribute compiling to multiple hosts:

```
export DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS='localhost red green blue'
cd ~/work/myproject; 
make -j8 CC=distcc
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU parallel is quite good. @Maxim - good suggestion +1.

For a one off, if you cannot install new software, try this for a slow command that has to run multiple times, run slowcommand 17 times. Change things to fit your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
cnt=0

while [ $cnt -le 17  ]    # loop 17 times
do
   slow_command  &
   cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
   [  $(( $cnt % 5 )) -eq  0 ] && wait  # 5 jobs at a time in parallel 
done
wait      # you will have 2 jobs you di not wait for in the loop 17 % 5 == 2
```

Comment: If you are allowed to run the BASH script above, you can also run GNU Parallel. See how under "Minimal installation": http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README?id=edac400fdf6c997967c6ba9332eb493b8aaddba8